# how to use powershell to exec the command and get result

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to user powershell to exec the command and get the execute result

let's say i want to use msival2.exe to certificate the msi installation package, and the exe will give me the information DURING the certification process..

I use `Invoke-Expression` and like that...

```
$out_put = Invoke-Expression ".\msival2.exe $msiPackageName darice.cub"
```

I could get the result from $out_put, ONLY AFTER the certification....

How could I get the result DURING the process of command just like I run the msival2.exe manually...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to collect the output from `msival2.exe` and at the same time see the output on the screen as it appears, I would suggest using the call operator `&`, and use `Tee-Object` to copy the output to a variable:

```
& .\msival2.exe $msiPackageName darice.cub |Tee-Object -Variable out_path
```